# OrchardCMS Getting the Attached Layout Part from the CustomType object in a Shape Alias

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to build a component for my Orchard Website.
I am using a Custom ContentType and shape tracing.
Its going exactly as I expect, but one of the parts is the `LayoutPart`.
All the other fields I am using to generate the HTML structure of the component.
In the center of it, I was going to display whatever the user puts into a `LayoutPart` inside of the middle of it.

**EDIT**
Was missing the Placement.info text. 
**/EDIT**

The ContentType has the following fields (which I am using to build the html):

- ID (Text)
- NextItem (NextItem)
- ModuleType (Text)
- BackGroundImage MediaImage

and the following ContentParts

- CommonPart
- NavigationPart
- LayoutPart

What I need is the LayoutPart from the Model object, so I can place its content in a div the cshtml with 
`BuildDisplay(layoutPart, "DisplayType")`

I have tried looking through the docs, and googling it.
I suspect that since I am new to both Orchard and Razor I don't have the right vocabulary yet.

Fixed Thank you!
Here's my final code:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Layouts.Models;
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes
@using Orchard.Layouts.Helpers;

@{
var tag = Tag(Model, "div");
    var id = Model.Content.Items[0].Value;
    var css = Model.Content.Items[1].ContentField.Value;
    var nextID = Model.Content.Items[2].ContentField.Value;
    var backgroundPath = Model.Content.Items[3].ContentField.FirstMediaUrl;

    var customstyle = "";

    if (css == "module-hero")
    {
        css = "module-hero fullheight parallax";
        customstyle = "background-image: url(" + backgroundPath + "); background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; ";
    }
    else if (css == "module-sidekick")
    {
        customstyle = "background-image: url(" + backgroundPath + "); background-size: cover; background-position: relative; background-repeat: no-repeat; overflow: hidden;";
    }
}
@tag.StartElement

<div id="@id" style="@customstyle" class="@css">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 m-t-250">
                @Display(Model.ParallaxContent)
                <div class="btn-list">
                    <a href="#@nextID" class="btn btn-outline smoothscroll"><i style="font-size: 60px" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@tag.EndElement

<!-- XML -- >
Placement.info 
<Match ContentType="ParallaxModule" DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_Layout="ParallaxContent" />
</Match>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits. :) I had issues with getting stack exchange to accept my code section. Which was frustrating since I cut and pasted it directly from Visual Studio, all formatted nicely.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is Shape Relocation. There is an introduction to it here in [Sebastien's Harvest 2015 Shapes Talk](https://youtu.be/gKLjtCIs4GU?t=56m49s).

The idea is as follows:

- You want to move a part around on the page but you don't want to take full control over the rendering of it, you just want to move the existing bit to somewhere else on the page.

### Shape Relocation

First you make up a new zone in your view, name it what you like. In your case it would look something like this:

```
<div id="@id" style="background: url(@backgroundPath)" class="@css">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 m-t-250">
                @Display(Model.MyNewCustomLayoutZone)
                <div class="btn-list">
                    <a href="#@nextID" class="btn btn-outline smoothscroll"><i style="font-size: 60px" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now you have a new zone which you can target with `placements.info` called `MyNewCustomLayoutZone`.

Open up the `placements.info` file in your theme or module and add this into it:

```
<Match ContentType="MyCustomContentType">
   <Match DisplayType="Detail">
      <Place Parts_Layout="MyNewCustomLayoutZone" />
   </Match>
</Match>
```

Where `MyCustomContentType` is whatever you have called this new content type and `MyNewCustomLayoutZone` is whatever you called your new zone in the first step.

### How do you find out the Parts_Layout bit?

Open up the shape tracing tool and go to the Part / Field you want to move around.

In the first tab, Shape you will see an entry Shape which tells you this.

[image: Shape tracer]

You can actually use the same technique to move around your fields.

You don't need to make a new zone every time, you can use the existing ones such as:

```
<Place Parts_Layout="Footer" />
```

If you wanted to show that bit at the end of this shape.

You can also move it around into shapes that are part of the wider page. These are called global zones. For example if I had created a field of type Text and it was called FooterText I could display it right at the bottom of the site with:

```
<Place Fields_Common_Text-FooterText="/Footer:after"/>
```

More info about your options with moving stuff around is in the [Understanding the placement.info file](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/) over on the official docs.

### Hiding custom fields

If you're seeing your custom fields in your main `@Display(Model.Content)` that you don't want to be displayed to the end-user you can simply hide them with `placement.info` using a `-` as the target zone.

This would translate into something like this:

```
<Match ContentType="MyCustomContentType">
   <Match DisplayType="Detail">
      <Place Fields_Common_Text-ID="-" />
      <Place Fields_NextItem-NextItem="-" />
      <Place Fields_Common_Text-ModuleType="-" />
      <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-BackGroundImage="-" />
   </Match>
</Match>
```

Comment: The names of the Fields are: ItemID, ModuleType, BackgroundImage,NextItemHref

Comment: var id = Model.Content.ItemID.Value; gives and error "Model.Content.ItemID.Value 'Model.Content.ItemID.Value' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' dynamic {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}"

Comment: with var part = Model.ContentItem.Content.LayoutPart; gives error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HtmlString' to 'string'"

Comment: layoutPart = BuildDisplay(part); gives error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Orchard.UI.Zones.ZoneHolding' to 'string'

Comment: I'm not asking about the Field Part, I figured there was a better way. But since I am the only coder for a moment, that part would work for now.  I at this time just need to Layout part that I added to the ContentType that I created. I don't want the whole thing just whatever they put in there rendered as html. Wish I could post pictures.

Comment: Ok I guess I should rewrite this answer as there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: First I want to thank you for your assistance. I think this is almost what I need.  What I want is to take the ContentType and using the fields to complete the style and css parts of the HTML above. and then using the Layout attached to the ContentType. and insert the generated content for that portion alone in the spot above. This site will be maintained by marketing people so I want to make this simple as possible but not restrictive. They can put in a HTML item, a Gallery.. whatever there.  I think this placement.info thing I am missing might be a big part in getting that internal Layout.

Comment: So are you avoiding rendering `Display(Model.Content)` because it has all those extra fields you defined knocking around in the way? You can hide them without having to do any of the above. I'll add a section.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I modified the code above to reflect my final changes.